New Bike - gear shifter installed on the left and upside down? Easy fix?
New bike (flat bar , gravel bike) came with the gear lever on the left side and upside down. Dropper post lever on the right side of bars, and on top of the bar. Any reason for this, and is it an easy fix to swap them around?
The cabling for each runs up the respective sides so assume this would have to be re-run.

Could you add a photo?

Was it a bike-in-a-box delivered to you? As in did you fit the handlebars upside down and need to flip them 180.

Or (@WarrenBurton) are the spanner monkeys getting worse?  There is another possibility though: that the OP or assembler has put the bars on correctly for the handedness they expect the brakes to be, but the bars were assembled for the other handedness, so getting the brakes right gets everything else wrong.  A close look at the brake levers would help, because the bleed port (assuming hydraulic) and any printed text (not cast/moulded, and pretty much any brake) should face upwards.  Cables can cross in front of the headtube, and often do as built.  It can make for gentler (better) bends
